# How can I display record when the SQL statement will select from an array in the database

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql="Select * from tbl_announcement where recipients='BSIT' or recipients='WITS';
```

it will select from the database but the database is in an array. How can I display th event:

[image]

Comment: Be more specific in asking your question. Provide a complete table layout in sql, any relevant source you've got so far, and a detailed description of what you're after.

Comment: As I understand, you want to get the recipients list detail. Is it right ?

Comment: If you capture the result of the query in a variable `$result` you can get the event by using `$result->event` if it is an object, or `$result['event']` if it is an array.

Comment: i want to display the events coming from the database when the recipient is BSIT, but there are times that there are two or more recipient like (BSIT,CHS,BSOA ) so what code should i put so that it can detect 1 by 1 the recipients and if the code detect that the recipients has BSIT then it will display the events..

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing CSV data in a column then to search part of the values use `FIND_IN_SET` function.

**Example**:

```
select * from tbl_announcement
 where FIND_IN_SET( 'BSIT', recipients )
    or FIND_IN_SET( 'WITS', recipients )
```

**Documentation**:

- [***FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

  - Returns a value in the range of 1 to N if the string str is in the
    string list strlist consisting of N substrings. A string list is a
    string composed of substrings separated by “,” characters.

Comment: It works thank you very much .i really dont know what to do till now well thank you very very much ..

Comment: Let me hope you got the answer right. [*Accepting Answers: How does it work*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)?